# How to stream video from my WebRTC to Facebook RTMP server directly?

Tags: javascript, python, webrtc, facebook-live-api

I'm trying to develop a web application with WebRTC and I'm getting video from my webcam through WebRTC and I want to do live streaming on Facebook and YouTube with my browser I have searched python and node js libraries but I haven't find any library for that. I want to build an application like [streamyard.com](https://streamyard.com).
I have watched ffmpeg

Comment: Since WebRTC and RTMP are different protocols, you can't do it directly.

Comment: Duplicated to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238148/how-to-use-webrtc-to-stream-video-to-rtmp

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using Pion WebRTC and ffmpeg!

I have created a demo [here](https://github.com/pion/example-webrtc-applications/tree/master/twitch). If you have ffmpeg installed and the Go compiler this *should* just work!

This takes audio/video from the browser, and then constructs a webm in memory. It then passes this WebM to ffmpeg via a stdin pipe, which then is transcode and sent to Twitch!

There are a lot of optimizations we could make here (like taking H264 from the browser directly) but H264 isn't supported everywhere, so this just makes the sample easier to reason with.