# broadcast a web-cam to (YouTube, Twitch , facebook) using HTML5 and WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, broadcast, rtmp, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm working on a project where i need to broadcast a live video on ***youtube***,  ***twitch*** , ***Facebook***  or other platforms from my website using HTML5 , rtmp , webrtc, nodejs....

so instead of going to youtube and start a live video, i want to start the video from my website

but  im new to webrtc and live streaming and i don't know what to do or how to start this so please if anyone have any ideas or suggestions about how to do this please contact me or leave a comment here

this is what i did

#### SERVER SIDE (NodeJs)

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) =>{

    socket.on('stream', stream =>{
        console.log(stream)
        socket.broadcast.emit('stream', stream);
      
            
    });

})
```

#### Client Side

Html (video.html)

```html
<div id="videos">
    <video id="video" autoplay>

    </video>

</div>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="js/video.js"></script>
```

Javascript (video.js)

```js
var socket = io();
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video  : true,
    audio: true
})
.then(stream =>{
    document.getElementById('video').srcObject = stream
    socket.emit("stream", stream);
})

socket.on('stream', stream=>{

    video = document.createElement("video")
    video.srcObject = stream
    video.setAttribute('autoplay')
    document.getElementById("videos").appendChild(video)
})
```

Comment: This is indeed a great question for newbies like me. Did you find out a good solution for Node.js?

Comment: If you accept answers on time, people will be more glad to assist you : )

Comment: Duplicated to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238148/how-to-use-webrtc-to-stream-video-to-rtmp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to do a `WebRTC to RTMP` bridge on your backend.

There are a lot of things to consider, but this is a common question so I threw together [twitch](https://github.com/pion/example-webrtc-applications/tree/master/twitch). It is an example of doing this.

Comment: thank you for your answer and yeah this what im trying to do but i dont know how  , do you have any  code examples please

Comment: Yes it is linked in the answer. It is a Go program that uses `pion/webrtc` and ffmpeg

Comment: yes thank you, do you know any nodejs or python examples

Comment: Sean is correct.- Here is my example in Node, using FFMPEG to convert the WebRTC to RTMP:  https://github.com/dougsillars/browserLiveStream

Comment: @DougSillars: your demo works very well. Thank you.

Comment: @DougSillars i am also using your demo which is working very well with custom RTMP server. Same script isn't working when trying to use it with Facebook broadcast api's RTMP server. Do you have any idea what may be the reason ?

Comment: @RaviRoshan - The demo uses RTMP, but for Facebook, you need RTMPS (secure RTMP): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/live-video-api/