# How to use webRTC to broadcast video using RTMP server

Tags: webrtc, streaming, live, rtmp

How can I stream the video from browser to RTMP URL? I want to achieve live streaming from the browser, for capturing webCam video and audio I use webRTC to display on a webpage. Now I want to send that video and audio on RTMP URL. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Unreal Media Server, Wowza

Comment: how, any video or example

Comment: You publish via WebRTC to media server; from that media server you can do RTMP push or pull. Demos: http://umediaserver.net/umediaserver/demos.html

Comment: Where you able to do this ? Any open source solutions ?

Comment: Yes using Agora and ant media

Comment: Duplicated to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238148/how-to-use-webrtc-to-stream-video-to-rtmp