# Apache + Nginx Server With RTMP Live Streaming

Tags: apache, nginx, server, rtmp, live-streaming

I am using CWP Pro (Control Web Panel)

I have selected webserver = Apache + Nginx

I want to install RTMP and want to live stream on my website with obs studio.

My queries are =

1. Do I need to install NGINX even if I am using Apache+Nginx server ?
2. Maximum tutorials / search results are showing NGINX + RTMP installation guide. Do I need to install NGINX too ? Or only RTMP module ?
3. After installing RTMP, I have created url for streaming  (e.g. rtmp://my_ip_address/live/stream_key), and added it in OBS studio. Started OBS streaming. But I am stuck at Code To Embed this live streaming in my html page of my website. How Can I EMbed it with video player lie video.js or other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider about this solution in two parts:

1. CWP, the admin control dashboard, to manage your system and live streams.
2. Media System, the live streaming system, to publish by OBS, to play the live stream by some proper protocols.

Generally, there are some HTTP Callback and HTTP-API between the two system, so it's better to deploy and build them separately.

For Media System, the generally workflow is:

1. Generate the live stream URL by your CWP system, like the RTMP url you mentioned.
2. Use encoder, OBS as such, to publish the RTMP stream. RTMP is the widely used protocol by encoder, SRT is an optional, WebRTC is also able to publish live stream now, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70402692/17679565).
3. Depends on your scenarios, H5 or Mobile, use some players to play the live stream. Well, it's complex, but **RTMP definitely doesn't work**, please use HLS/HTTP-FLV/DASH/WebRTC, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358918/17679565).

There are some commercial solutions too, which does the same things.